# What does the '!' at the end of my code do?

Tags: flutter, dart

`Text(locations[index].location!)`

without the '!' I get the next error:
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asserts that a nullable value is not null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locations[index].location` can return null, using `!` we are saying, the value of it won't be null. Text widget doesn't accept null value.

It is better to do a null check 1st on nullable data like

```dart
if (locations[index].location != null) Text(locations[index].location)
```

or you can provide default value

```dart
Text(locations[index].location ?? "got null")
```

You can also do

```
Text("${locations[index].location}");
```

Comment: But then why does ! solve the error?

Comment: Throw a error at runtime if the value is null

Comment: Because using `!` we are saying this value isnt null

Comment: I really recommend putting spaces at the appropiate places. Your code is correct but is against coding conventions.

Comment: @Ivo thank you, feel free to update, I am directly typing here sorry for the conventions.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh - You don't need the exclamation mark after checking if the variable is not equal to null...

Comment: @tomerpacific yes you are right, feel free to make the update

Comment: @YeasinSheikh - Seeing as it is your code, you should be responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation mark (!) in Dart tells the code that you are sure this variable can never be null. ***It is an unsafe way of dealing with variables that may be null***.

In your case, the type of the variable is String?, which means that it may be null or a String.

To safely unwrap a nullable variable, it is advised to do the following:

```
if (locations[index].location != null) {
  //Do your logic here
}
```

[Null Safety Documentation](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Answer (score 0):

It means it is a nullable type, which means it can be initialized without any value.